# The Function is breaking before providing all values

Tags: python, list, function

```
def list_num_checker(num_list):
    for x in num_list:
        if x%2==0:
            return x 
        else:
            continue
```

I just began learning Python and this is the code I have written to create a function to return all the even values in a list. However, It breaks down after checking the first even number.E.g.

```
list_num_checker([1,2,3,4,5,6])
2
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `return` means exit this function and hand back this value

Comment: `return x` will immediately end the function. Instead, create an empty list, then append those values in the list if condition true, then at the end, return the list

Comment: `return` will end the function execution. You can turn this into generator using `yield`, but I don't know if it is something you learned already. Also, the `else` part is redundant.

Comment: can return somehow be used to say get the full list.  using some other character maybe?

Comment: you can create new list (append to it in regular loop or use list comprehension) to hold all even numbers and return that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return will cause a function to exit... if you use yield you can make it a generator

```
def list_num_checker(num_list):
    for x in num_list:
        if x%2==0:
            yield x # yield makes this a generator instead
        # else: # you don need the else
        #    continue

for evennum in list_num_checker([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]):
    print(evennum)
```

you could also make a list comprehension

```
print([x for x in num_list if x%2 == 0])
```

or you could use the builtin filter function

```
def is_even(num):
    return num % 2 == 0

list(filter(is_even,num_list)) # its a generator so you need to call list on it
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `yield` instead of `return` since `return` will break the `for` loop and immediately returns the give value

```
def list_num_checker(num_list):
    for x in num_list:
        if x%2==0:
            yield x
        else:
            continue

divisible2 = list(list_num_checker([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

Some possible alternative approaches would be to use list comprehension or `filter`

```
def list_num_checker(num_list):
    return [x for x in num_list if x % 2 == 0]
```

```
def list_num_checker(num_list):
    return filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, num_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` will immediately terminate the function. To produce multiple values in one function, use `yield` instead.

```
def list_num_checker(num_list):
    for x in num_list:
        if x%2==0:
            yield x 
        else:
            continue
```